# Static imports vs. definition delegation

Tags: java

According to [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=195) one should usually avoid using static imports. I get that. I want to know, however, what the difference between the two practices below is:

#### Code Sample #1

In the first sample, I statically import `SomeClass.someMethod`, and use it within the context of my own class, omitting any name qualifiers.

```
import static package1.SomeClass.someMethod;
package package2;
public class MyClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        someMethod("Hello");
    }
}
```

#### Code Sample #2

In the second sample, I import the class itself, and then redirect the call to the method qualified by its full name.

```
import package1.SomeClass;
package package2;
public class MyClass {
    private void someMethod(String text) {
        SomeClass.someMethod(text);
    }
    public void doSomethind() {
        someMethod("Hello");
    }
}
```

What is the essential difference between the two? And I mean beyond the very obvious advantages proxying a call would give us (e.g. event hooks, parameter monitoring, etc.)
In particular, I want to know if there are any best practices regarding this, and if this has a performance-related guideline.

Comment: In the second example you are not importing "the class itself", you are importing the package to which the class belongs.

Comment: @skiwi that is not true

Comment: @skiwi It appears for example purposes the asker is using the default package. So the import in example 2 is correct, though unnecessary if MyClass is also in the default package. The asker should use example packages to make this question more clear.

Comment: @PhilippSander Ah ok, I'm not used to classes being in default package. So my mistake there.

Comment: @skiwi package imports and with `.*;`

Comment: @skiwi added package names, though that was not very relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the essential difference between the two?

There is no difference except for code readability

Found explanation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

> So when should you use static import? **Very sparingly!** Only use it when you'd otherwise be tempted to declare local copies of constants, or to abuse inheritance (the Constant Interface Antipattern). In other words, **use it when you require frequent access to static members from one or two classes.**

Regarding code readability

> If you overuse the static import feature, it can make your program unreadable and unmaintainable, polluting its namespace with all the static members you import. Readers of your code (including you, a few months after you wrote it) will not know which class a static member comes from. Importing all of the static members from a class can be particularly harmful to readability; if you need only one or two members, import them individually. **Used appropriately, static import can make your program more readable, by removing the boilerplate of repetition of class names.**

Comment: `Readers of your code will not know which class a static member comes from`---that's a classic strawman argument. Every IDE makes it *effortless* to find out what stems from where. And how come the same argument is never applied to plain *class* imports? How on Earth do we know which *package* all those classes come from?

Comment: In my experience I had several classes with same static method names.  Importing them statically could cause confusion. You have method name collisions more often then class names

Comment: Yes, it puts more pressure on the programmer to choose names wisely. Some cases, like `Integer.valueOf`, are a perfect match for a non-static import. Others, like `Math.abs`, are a perfect target for a static import. Trouble comes between these extremes, when names *could* have been chosen better with the static import feature in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> one should usually avoid using static imports

If that was true, the feature would never have been added to the language. It was added late, which means the decision was based on years of experience and millions of lines of code.

The problem lies not with the feature of static import, but rather with the naming choice for the static members:

```
UserManager.instance
```

is a typical example of bad naming choice. It is unfortunately the *de facto* standard in legacy code, and much of the modern code does not cater to static imports, either.

```
UserManager.userManager
```

is an example of a name tailor-made for the static import feature.

I would rather turn this issue upside-down and start ranting on the library makers who obstruct their users in leveraging the static import feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about personal preference.

There are also no significant performance differences when compiling or executing.

I would always use non-static imports since some people don't know what static imports do and they confuse them.

Answer (score 0):

To your question

> what the difference between the two practices below is..

The answer is, there is none.  This is just two ways to solve a problem.  Either way works.  One may be more preferred than the other, but there is essentially no difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

> The difference between the two

*There is no difference between the two except `Code Sample #1` saves some keystrokes(refer 2nd point) and improves readability(here conditions apply refer 3rd point)*

> 1.use `static imports` to kick out [Constant Interface Antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface).
>
> 2.use `static import` ,when you require frequent access to static members from one or two classes. For example if you are frequently using System.out.println() statements and tried of typing it, you can `static import System.out`.
>
> 3.If you overuse the `static import` feature, it can make your program unreadable and unmaintainable, polluting its namespace with all the static members you import.